# Language dependent conjunctions in cleveref

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, babel, cleveref

I want to add language dependent conjunctions to `cleveref`. I think that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\addto\captionsngerman{%
    \crefname{section}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}%
    \newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ und }%
}


\begin{document}
    \section{title}\label{1}
    \section{title}\label{2}

    \cref{1,2}
\end{document}
```

should work (and the output is indeed correct). However I get the error `Command \crefpairconjunction already defined. \select@language{ngerman}`. If I change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand`, the error becomes `\crefpairconjunction undefined. \select@language{ngerman}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code inside of `\addtocaptions` is called multiple times, so at the 2nd usage `\crefpairconjunction` is defined already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is added to the German captions is not added just once, but called multiple times, so after the first usage it would be alright, but in the next calls, `\crefpairconjunction` is already defined and can't be defined again, other than using `\renewcommand`.

It is possible to see the multiple call of the added code with `\typeout{foo}` after or before `\crefname...` -- you will see 3 'foo's in on the terminal etc. screen.

One possibility is to define a global `\crefpairconjunction` that is empty or has some default value in the beginning and then redefine it to be expand to `und` in the `\addto\captions....` usage or check for the existence with `\@ifundefined`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \crefname{section}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}%
  \@ifundefined{crefpairconjunction}{\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ und }}{}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \section{title}\label{1}
    \section{title}\label{2}

    \cref{1,2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a default and then use `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\providecommand\crefpairconjunction{ and }

\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \crefname{section}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ und }%
}


\begin{document}

\section{title}\label{1}

\section{title}\label{2}

\cref{1,2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\providecommand`?

Comment: @JohnDorian Maybe one loads packages that already define it; who knows?

Comment: @JohnDorian: `\providecommand` acts like `\newcommand` if the command isn't there already, otherwise it does nothing