# Changing the connective "and" in a \cref multiple referencing

Tags: cleveref

I am using **\cref** in my Persian document. I want to change the connective "**and**" to its Persian counterpart when I am using \cref for multiple referencing. By multiple referencing, I mean putting several entities, say theorems, in one single \cref command; example:
\cref{thmTech, thmMain}.

This command outputs something like: "theorem 2.3 and 2.5".

I am wondering if "**cleveref**" package has an easy-to-use command for this?

If exists, it must be like the command "**\crefname**" used for changing the title-name of the counters: 
\crefname{chapter}{CH.}{CH.s}
If you want "CH.s 1 and 2" instead of "chapters 1 and 2" in your output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) As often when you have a package specific question, and even more when asking about the capabilities of a package, a good starting point might be to look at the package documentation. The documentation for `cleveref` [is here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf). Section 8.2.3 have the answer you are searching for. Moreover, if you are using `babel` package, I invite you to look at section 10 of this documentation.

Comment: Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423395/language-dependent-conjunctions-in-cleveref/

Comment: Note that this only works for two references, for something like `\cref{ref1,ref2,ref3}` you need to define different commands. There are a few languages that are already implemented by cleveref (such as German and French), see the cleveref source code to check which commands you need to redefine for which situations.

Comment: @Marijn: Thanks for your suggestion. But, as you said, my question is not yet answered for more than two references. I think my question must remain open to find the full answer!

Comment: @userA if you edit your question to provide a compilable minimal example document with more than two references (such that, when the code is copied from the question and compiled, it results in a pdf file with the incorrect use of _and_ but not much other content) then it will probably be reopened.